# linux tbf rate limiting not functioning as expected

Tags: linux, networking

I wanted to test how the latency of a packet would be affected by rate limiting the throughput of an interface. I have an interface named veth-red. It will received ICMP packet and routes it to veth-green. The veth-green then responds with the ICMP respone.

I was sending an ICMP packet of 1500 byte and wanted to set the rate on veth-red to be 10000 bits per second, so that I will get the response after 1.2 seconds. I used the following

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev veth-red root tbf rate 10000bit burst 12kbit latency 5000ms
```

Unexpectedly, I received the ping response in 0.057 ms. Also as soon as I change the burst to some value under 12kbit, my response is failing. How should I set the rate properly to see my expected behavior.

I have posted this question in the askubuntu forum but did not get any answer or suggestion.

Comment: Sorry Roaima. It was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The Linux traffic shapers (and Ethernet) work a packet at time and do not increase the time it takes to a single packet, rather they increase the time between packets.

If you set the maximum burst to smaller than a packet then it can't send the packet.